# Symfony 2 - make actions from bundle inside other bundle

Tags: symfony, bundle

I have problem with that concept: I want to have bundle forum (display comments, adding new, etc.), but I want to display it in another bundle (lets say url: /articles/showforum). I can include forum inside /articles/showforum, but links will be the old ones (e.g. to show form to add new topic: /forum/newtopic). I want sth like /articles/showforum/forum/newtopic - is there such a tool in Symfony 2 to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can set base routing for your ForumBundle. Here using annotations:

```
/**
* Forum controller
*
* @Route("/articles/showforum/forum")
*/
class ForumController extends Controller
{...
```

A base editAction method:

```
\ForumBundle\ForumController.php
public function editAction($id)
{   
    $this->editCustom(id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}

public function editCustom(id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('ForumBundle:Topic')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Topic entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createForm(new TopicType(), $entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
}

\ArticlesBundle\ForumController.php
public function editAction($id)
{   
    \ForumBundle\Controller\ForumController::editCustom(id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}
```

Comment: but what if I want to have also /photos/showforum ? And it doesn't resolve problem with urls (template showing forum will have links such as /forum/newtopic, /forum/reply, etc., I want them to point to bundle which is container, with their actions redirected to forumcontroller)

Comment: You have to change approach then. Just create your ForumBundle as if you'll use it without including it in another bundle. Than create a PhotosBundle (the same for ArticlesBundle) with all methods you need in his controller and call ForumBundle's methods thanks to namespaces.

Comment: But what with links from ForumBundle templates? They will redirect always to ForumBundle main template (instead ArtcilesBundle templates containing ForumBundle template).

Comment: Create methods with only logic and call them from your main methods (new, create, edit, update...), so you can set then the template to use whereevere you're.

Comment: maybe small example? I don't know exactly what do you mean by "main methods" and how call them from template (i can call methods only by url, aren't I?)

Comment: hmm, I almost get the idea, but I've one more question - how are you passing variables from editCustom to editAction? Is this some kind of symfony magic or is this simplification of example?

Comment: And how are you calling these non-static functions like static?

Comment: Simplification of example. This code is only to help you understand what I think, don't think at it as production code.